# SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase vs SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, dataadapter, sqliteopenhelper

Is there any difference between these two methods? Both return an opened SQLiteDatabase. Both can create a database if one doesn't exist. SQLiteOpenHelper also has getWriteableDatabase when read/write is needed...

Which method should I use and where? Based on sample code I've seen, I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper to create my database in the first place, but then calling SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase when I need to use the database.

Answer (score 3):

The `openDatabase()` is more flexible allowing you to specify locale etc. but for most circumstances where you don't need to explicitly supply those details the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) says to use `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWriteableDatabase()`.

Comment: Also, note that `getReadableDatabase()` will most likely just return `getWriteableDatabase()`. See [this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java).