# Open Database for ReadWirte not possible on specific device

Tags: android, sqlite

I simply try to open a database in READWRITE Mode. I get the following error: "not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode." When opening the DB the same way but READONLY is works.  On my 3 devices this is not a problem opening in READWRITE, but 2 users reported that following error.

the db exists on the users filesystem . I check this with file.exists() -> ok.
the db-file is readwrite able on the users device. I check this with file.canWrite() -> ok.

the dbfile is stored under :

StoragePath : /mnt/extSdCard/mypath/mydb.db

New Info on 09.03.2014 : It seems to be only a problem in KitKat 4.4.2. Since Users have updated to 4.4.2 they get this problem.

My Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


connectWriter(); // throws exception below.

public void connectWriter() {
        chronica_connection_readwrite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("MyPath", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        //chronica_connection_read.enableWriteAheadLogging();
    }
```

Exception Report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:342)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:232)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:891)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:859)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
at myclass.connectWriter(ChronicBrowser.java:14286)
at myclass.LoadModule(ChronicBrowser.java:10792)
at myclass.onCreate(ChronicBrowser.java:761)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)


************ DEVICE INFORMATION ***********
Brand: samsung
Device: hlte
Model: SM-N9005
Id: KOT49H
Product: hltexx

************ FIRMWARE ************
SDK: 19
Release: 4.4.2
Incremental: N9005XXUENB7
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `SQLiteOpenHelper`? You wouldn't have to deal directly with the database for opening in different modes.

Comment: I really would like to use my connection as mentoined. My database is not created by the app and I have no versioning. My db will be downloaded by my app.. I guess this should be possible to open a readwrite connection on every device. Any hints ?

Comment: Are all the devices running the same android version?
I'd suggest suign SQLiteOpenHelper, you can always maintain the version number in your app. I don't think that's a good excuse not to use SQLiteOpenHelper. I also download the db file into my app from an external source and yet I am using SQLiteOpenHelper and maintaining the version inside my app.

Comment: I will try it, but according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373722/sqlitedatabase-opendatabase-vs-getwritabledatabase there is no need to use  SQLiteOpenHelper to open a database in readwrite mode. I aslo like to use "enableWriteAheadLogging" logging, which I do not know how this is supported by SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193279/sqlitedatabase-opendatabase-vs-sqliteopenhelper-getreadabledatabase . There seems no difference between SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase vs SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase regarding opening a db.

Comment: News on this : It seems only to be a problem with KitKat Android 4.4.2. Users reported, that the error occurs after updating to KitKat. A bug probably :-(

Comment: Confirm: I do have the same problem. While app was in 4.2 everything was fine, but now when I have upgraded to KitKat I see problem. Issue roots are the same - I have db on SD card. Device is SGS-4. Please help!

Comment: As another way you can try to store your data in alternate db like JDBM or simply excel file if you don't need protect your storage

Comment: The Problem is, that also handling with files (write) is a problem in KITKAT. I just got a errorreport regarding unzipping a file on a filesystem, which works great since 2 years. :-( KitKat has a problem with write access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that this is not bug, but "feature".

[Google's KitKat Blocks Some Access to Micro SD Cards](http://lifehacker.com/android-kitkat-blocks-some-access-to-micro-sd-cards-1524997895)

It's really sad, but looks like true

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by moving the database to internal storage on a Galaxy S4 after it upgraded to 4.4.2.  I agree it's sad, as it now uses up internal memory while there is plenty on the SD card.  Hopefully there is another way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this by saying you should really be storing SQLite databases on internal storage, where you have the benefit of ext4 journaling to help with data recovery.  There is also *much* better security on internal storage, since you don't have to worry about malicious apps adding triggers, etc that end up running in your process.

That all being said, starting in KitKat you can write to secondary storage devices through the new public APIs `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()` or `Context.getExternalCacheDirs()`.  These methods are also available on `ContextCompat` in the support-v4 library.

Also note that if you're only interested in using the directories returned by `Context`, you no longer need the `READ_` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.  Going forward, you'll always have read/write access to these directories with no additional permissions required.

Apps can also continue working on older devices by end-of-lifing their permission request like this:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: So, using these APIs `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()`, help us to store SQLite db in the secondary storage ? I think these are the APIs for storing some files related to our app but not sqlite db. Please correct me if I am wrong.